# Make rsync update files transferred in previous executions

Tags: rsync

## Minimal working example

1. Let's suppose we have two directories `a` and `b`
2. File `1.txt` exists in `a` and it contains `foo`
3. We copy `a/1.txt` to `b` using `rsync`
4. File `a/1.txt` gets modified and now it contains `bar`
5. In order to have the updated version of `a/1.txt` in `b`, we execute `rsync` again

At this point `a/1.txt` contains `bar`, while `b/1.txt` contains `foo`.

The scenario described above can be reproduced by executing the following commands.

```sh
mkdir a b
echo foo > a/1.txt
rsync -a a/ b
echo 'After first run'
cat a/1.txt
cat b/1.txt

echo bar > a/1.txt
rsync -a a/1.txt b/
echo 'After second run'
cat a/1.txt
cat b/1.txt
```

```
After first run
foo
foo
After second run
bar
foo
```

As you could see above, the content of `b/1.txt` was not updated with the content of `a/1.txt` in the second run.

## The question

How to make `rsync` update the content of files that have been copied in a previous run?

## System information

```
$ rsync --version
```

```
rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2022 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: https://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, symlinks, symtimes, hardlinks, hardlink-specials,
    hardlink-symlinks, IPv6, atimes, batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs,
    xattrs, optional secluded-args, iconv, prealloc, stop-at, no crtimes
Optimizations:
    SIMD-roll, no asm-roll, openssl-crypto, no asm-MD5
Checksum list:
    xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4 sha1 none
Compress list:
    zstd lz4 zlibx zlib none
Daemon auth list:
    sha512 sha256 sha1 md5 md4

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this either on NTFS with Cygwin or native ext4 on Linux (Debian). For me, `rsync` works as expected and gives `foo`/`foo` then `bar`/`bar`. What filesystem are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` normally compares the sizes & modification times of files in the source and target, and if they match it assumes the files are the same. In this example, the files have the same size (4 bytes) and b/1.txt was modified so closely after a/1.txt that the timestamps came out the same.

If you add a `sleep 1` command between the two sections of the script, it should work (unless you're on a FAT volume -- it only has 2-second resolution in timestamps, so you'll have to delay 2 seconds to get consistent results).

Alternately, you could add the `-I` flag to `rsync` to make it ignore timestamps, and actually veryify that the files' contents match (or at least their checksums).